# Cordova push notification plugin

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

I am developing an app using Cordova. My app needs to receive different push notifications and then act accordingly like open the app with data got through notification etc. I have seen [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) which can receive the notification and launch the app. But what I have understood is that when app is closed and push notification comes and user taps on notification, it will just launch the app from beginning but my requirement is to open a particular web page from the app. So can this be done using this or some other plugin or I would have to manually code the push notification handling for Android, iOS separately?

Comment: there is an issue for this https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/210